# Import Workspace Sibling

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I do not understand why Cargo is failing to resolve a local import in a workspace project I have created. I will detail the problem below, but for those that wish to see a working example I have created [a demo repo](https://github.com/danforbes/rust-help).

In this example `consumer.rs` is failing to compiling w/ the following error: `` use of undeclared crate or module `producer` ``

What makes things even more confusing for me is that rust-analyzer for VSCode seems to be able to kind of resolve the import (it is underlined in red, but Intellisense works).

What is the correct way to set-up my project so that Cargo can resolve my local import?

Cargo.toml

```ini
[workspace]
members = [
    "consumer",
    "producer",
]

[profile.release]
panic = "unwind"
```

consumer/Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "consumer"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
producer = { path = "../producer" }
```

consumer/src/lib.rs

```rs
use producer::Foo;

pub fn get_foo() -> Foo {
    Foo::Bar
}
```

producer/Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "producer"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

producer/src/lib.rs

```rs
pub enum Foo {
    Bar
}
```

Comment: Why have you specified producer to be `"cdylib"`? You cannot use a dynamic library as a cargo dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crate-type` of `producer` cannot be `cdylib` as this will produce a library that is intended to be used from other languages (ref: [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html)). This confusion came about due to my limited experience with Rust as well as copypasta while exploring Rust for Wasm. I think in my case the best solution is just to remove the entire `[lib]` section from producer/Cargo.toml